# Angular 14: Routing to child route not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my Angular 14 application I have tree on the left side which contains buildings and persons inside these buildings.

```
    + Building 1
       - Person 1
       - Person 2
       - Person 3
    + Building 2
       - Person 4
       - Person 5
```

When I click an entry in the tree I want to display some details on the right side of the browser window. Therefore, I created a HTML template which contains the tree and a `<router-outlet>` for rendering the child components.

```html
      <div class="container">
        <div class="tree-container">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The routes are defined in this way:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        children: [
          { path: 'building/:uuid', component: BuildingComponent},
          { path: 'person/:uuid', component: PersonComponent},
        ]
      },
    ];
```

When I click an entry I call a method in the Maincomponent routing to the corressponding child compoment:

```js
    this.router.navigate(['building', buildingUuid], {relativeTo: this.route})

    or

    this.router.navigate(['person', personUuid], {relativeTo: this.route})
```

This works fine if I switch between building and person items. In this case the child component is shown in the right part of the browser window.

But when I click two nodes of the same type after each other (e.g. Person 1 and then Person 2) I see that the URL in the browser changes, but the child component is not updated.

Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are already navigated to that component, so the component is already created and will not be created again.

What you should do is to subscribe to the `params` in the `ngOnInit`, so your logic will be executed on each param change:

```js
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe({
    next: (params) => {
      const uuid = params.uuid;
      // Your logic
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    },
  });
}
```

**Note**: Don't forget to unsubscribe from Observable in `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: Subscribing to the params did the trick. I used the params from the snapshot before. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Yup, snapshot is a good practice when you don't have a use case like this. Consider also upvoting my answer, in case other people would have the same problem.